# How to restore Google Search withOUT Google Voice Dialer?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, google-voice, google-search, google-voice-actions

Stack Exchange newbie here.  Please forgive any protocol mistakes.

I'm following a thread, but can't yet comment as a newbie, on a question involving the Google Voice Dialer for Android 4.1x - everyone commenting knows that the prior version worked fine but a new OTA push made it serious junk.  I've followed some instructions that say to disable Google Search so that the system will use Voice Commands instead, and that solution works consistently well.  However, additional instructions state that one should then re-download Google Search to reinstall it. This does not appear possible... when an app is disabled, it indicates this status in the Play Store and one cannot opt to download a fresh copy.  And re-enabling Google Search just puts the crappy Google Voice Dialer back online.

How to restore Google Search withOUT Google Voice Dialer? Comments or answers to this please?  Your help greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Droid Bionic  4.1.2  System ver  98.72.22.XT875.Verizon.en.US